# how to use waitpid() to get the status of child process?

Tags: c++, system-calls

Im trying to get the status of child process. for example, when I run "adjsafkl" which is a not exist command, the system print "WRONG", but when I run "cp sssa" which the folder is not exist either, but the system will not mark this command as WRONG. I wonder is there anyway to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check for WEXITSTATUS after WIFEXITED:

> WIFEXITED: returns true if the child terminated normally, 
>       that is, by calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().
>
> WEXITSTATUS: returns the exit status of the child. 
>      This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status 
>      argument that the child specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) 
>      or as the argument for a return statement in main(). This macro 
>    should only be employed if WIFEXITED returned true.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually I tried that but its not work either :(

Comment: What did not work? If you bash cp with wrong data, it should exit with value '1'.

Comment: Yes, but when I add some arguments like "ls -ffjaskaf" the return value is 0

Comment: @TonyHello No, it isn't. In my linux flavour it is '2', using "ls -ffjaskaf" and then "echo $?".

Comment: I got it!!! you are right! really thanks for your answer, and have a wonderful day :)

Comment: could you please try "ls -asfdsdf" for me?

Comment: @TonyHello in any case there is no other information available from `waitpid()` other than what is described in this answer. If this code doesn't do what you want, it can't be done.

Comment: @TonyHello try it by yourself in a shell, and after that, use "echo $?" to get the exit value from ls. If it is 0, ls is *telling* you everything is right.